# Javascript optimization of new Object() call on existing object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some front-end code that uses EJS and I am wondering about this code in particular:

```
<head>
<script>

    var data = new Object(<%-data%>);

    app.constant("NODE_ENV", data.NODE_ENV);

    app.constant("SUBJECT", {
            kind: data.kind,
            id: data.id,
            name: data.name,
            picture: data.picture,
            counts: data.counts
     });

   app.constant("FOLLOWS", data.follows);


</script>
</head>
```

(this pattern is more or less the JSON Configuration Object pattern using Angular.)

I am wondering with Javascript, if I call

```
var obj1 = {};
var obj2 = new Object(obj1);
```

will JS ignore the call to create a new object from the old one? Or will it do some weird cloning behavior?

Comment: Nvm. It doesn't create a clone, it sets obj2 = obj1. This is in chrome tho.

Comment: Interesting thing though. if you run your example, then set obj1.name = "anystring", then obj2 has the same property.

Comment: yeah, but that's simply because they hold the same reference

Comment: well, yeah, I'm saying that this behaviour shows that it doesn't create a clone.

Answer (score 2):

> The Object constructor creates an object wrapper for the given value.
>   If the value is null or undefined, it will create and return an empty
>   object, otherwise, it will return an object of a Type that corresponds
>   to the given value. **If the value is an object already, it will return
>   the value.**
>
> When called in a non-constructor context, Object behaves identically
>   to new Object().

—Direct quote from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object